# Equally spacing views using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm trying to space subviews equally (horizontally). Now these subviews don't all have the same width so it's a bit more complicated than the examples I've found on SO. Here's my VFL:

```
|[view0][view1][view2][view3][view4][view5]|
```

And this is the result:

[image]

So it just stretches the last view out to make it satisfy the constraint. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to include invisible spacer views between your icons and specify equal width for these spacer views:

```
|[view0][spacer0][view1][spacer1(==spacer0)][view2][spacer2(==spacer0)][view3][spacer3(==spacer0)][view4][spacer4(==spacer0)][view5]|
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html

Check out **Spacing and Wrapping** section.